# What is the difference between TIme.now + 1.day vs 1.day.from_now in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

recently I came across updating time in ruby with these two syntaxes:

`Time. now + 1. day`

and

`1.day.from_now`

so what is the difference between both, any performance difference or just syntax changes?
as I searched for the same, I didn't get a proper answer.

Comment: If you replace `Time.now` with `Time.current`, they should be equivalent.

Comment: Yep, ‘Time.now’ doesn’t care about time zone while ‘1.day.from_now’ includes the time zone in the result. In terms of performances I don’t think that the time zone handling is adding a significant overhead but could be interesting to benchmark

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that they will give different classes and potentially different results depending on your time zone settings.

The [`Time`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html) class is from the Ruby core and is not timezone aware. However Rails extensively monkeypatches this and other core classes.

`1.day` and `1.day.from_now` use core extensions (monkeypatches) to [Numeric defined by `ActiveSupport`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html) (which is bundled with Rails).

```
irb(main):007:0> 1.day
=> 1 day
irb(main):008:0> 1.day.class
=> ActiveSupport::Duration
```

`1.day` returns an `ActiveSupport::Duration` and when you call:

```
Time.now + 1.day
```

You're calling the `+` method monkeypatched onto the Time class by ActiveSupport:

```
irb(main):004:0> Time.now.method(:+)
=> #<Method: Time#+(plus_with_duration)(other) /home/max/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:280>
```

Which handles adding `ActiveSupport::Durations` to Time instances.

`from_now` is just an alias of `ActiveSupport::Duration#since` which converts a Duration into a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` timestamp.

```
irb(main):006:0> 1.day.from_now.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` most likely has some overhead since its wrapping a time instance - if it actually matters to the performance of your app is highly questionable.

See:

- [thoughtbot: It's About Time (Zones)](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones)

Answer (score 0):

`1.day.from_now` comes from Rails and is not core Ruby.

The difference is that one returns a `Time` object, the other returns an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`.

In the Rails console:

```rb
(Time.now + 1.day).class
#=> Time

(1.day.from_now).class
#=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

Rails defines `Time#current` As @Stefan says, `Time.current` is equivalent to the latter, returning an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instance.

Comment: `Time.now + 1.day` uses the monkeypatches `ActiveSupport::Duration` adds to numeric so is hardly "core ruby" either.